# Java LinkedHashSet backwards iteration

Tags: java, set, iteration, linkedhashset

How can I iterate through items of a `LinkedHashSet` from the last item to the first one?

Comment: Why in Java Collection Framework it is not included. LinkedHashSet maintains FIFO order so an utility to convert the order into LIFO should be there which seems to be vary handy when requirement is to maintain insertion order at the same time we may need to iterate in reverse order. In my project there were couple time I needed this already. Unfortunately, I have to use List as intermediary to take advantage of Collections.reverse() utility. This is dirty isn't it!

Comment: This has been a problem since forever. There are [proposals](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2021-April/076461.html) floating around to address it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want to continue to use collections, you could use the following:

```
LinkedHashSet<T> set = ...

LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<>(set);
Iterator<T> itr = list.descendingIterator();
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    T item = itr.next();
    // do something
}
```

If you're fine with using an array instead, you could take a look at [hvgotcodes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741952/758280).

Comment: The `new LinkedList<>(set)` will copy all items, won't it?

Comment: @Sasha Yes, it will.

Answer (score 7):

er, assuming you mean LinkedHashSet...

I would use [toArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) and just use a reverse for loop.

There might be a better way to do it, but that should work.  `toArray` guarantees any order is preserved

> If this set makes any guarantees as to what order its elements are
> returned by its iterator, this method must return the elements in the
> same order.

Something like

```
Set<MyType> mySet = new LinkedHashSet();
...
MyType[] asArray = mySet.toArray(new MyType[0]);

for (int i = asArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
..
}
```

Comment: your code seems cann't compile: `MyType[] asArray = mySet.toArray();`

Comment: Object array cannot be converted to MyType array. This code won't compile.

Comment: I just fixed that.

Answer (score 7):

This is another way:

```
LinkedHashSet<T> set = ...

List<T> list = new ArrayList<>(set);
Collections.reverse(list);

for( T item : list ){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really meant LinkedHashSet, you could put the elements into an ArrayList and then use the ArrayList's ListIterator.

```
ListIterator<T> l = new ArrayList<T>(yourLinkedHashList).listIterator();
// ListIterator can iterate in reverse
while(l.hasPrevious()) {
    T obj = l.previous();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 21, the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#reversed()) method on `LinkedHashSet` can be used.  This reversed view of the set can be used to iterate in reverse order.

```java
for (Object o : myLinkedHashSet.reversed()) {
  System.out.println(o);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now from java 21 onwards you can use `reversed()` method of `SequancedSet` to reverse a collection element.

```
LinkedHashSet lhs=....
....
.....
SequencedSet sequencedSet=lhs.reversed();
```

Answer (score -10):

From the javadoc: "This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order)."

So you can simply:

```
LinkedHashSet<Integer> numbers = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(33);
numbers.add(44);
numbers.add(108);

for (Integer i : numbers) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: "from the last one to the first one."