# Collection that prevents duplicates but preserves reversible duplicate insertion order?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, guava

Is there a collection that preserves reversible duplicate insertion order?

Specifically, if I insert the following items:

```
1
2
3
1
```

I want to be able to iterate over them and receive them in the following order:

```
1
3
2
```

That is, I want them in descending insertion order with duplicate insertions causing a reorder. [Guava's LinkedListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/LinkedListMultimap.html) is the closest I've found, but it doesn't support descending traversal.

[Java's LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) doesn't work because it doesn't allow descending traversal.

I could also use an LRU cache, but most LRU libraries I've found don't support retrieving objects in LRU order.

Does this thing have a standard name?

Comment: Did you take at look a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) ?

Comment: extend LinkedHashSet and maintain reverse order

Comment: What collection should I use flow chart, by @TimB: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974361/what-java-collection-should-i-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ListOrderedSet](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/set/ListOrderedSet.html) class of `org.apache.commons.collections4.set`.

For example:

```
listOrderedSet.add(1,1);
listOrderedSet.add(1,2);
listOrderedSet.add(1,3);
listOrderedSet.add(1,1);
```

This will give you the expected out put.

Comment: Somehow the Apache API's always make me itch a bit, using a special insertion method is not as clean as it should be, it's not a method that is part of the `Set` interface.

Comment: Yeah, the Apache collections are quite obsolete. Also I don't think this will work. Per the javadoc for the add method: "Inserts the specified element at the specified position if it is not yet contained in this ordered set (optional operation)." meaning if it is in there already the position won't change.

Answer (score 5):

How about using a [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and whenever you detect that the item is in there you remove it and reinsert it? That's the only way to guarantee the insertion order is what you expect (or the inverse thereof).

You can [`iterate over the LinkedHashSet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741902/java-linkedhashset-backwards-iteration) by creating a `LinkedList` over the `LinkedHashSet` and reversing over it in any way you like, e.g. by using Guava's [`Lists.reverse`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Lists) method.

Comment: Is there any way to reverse-iterate over the `LinkedHashSet`? Or are you required to create a reverse `LinkedList` representation of it?

Comment: I think you have to convert the set to a list and then you can use Guava's [`Lists.reverse`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Lists) method to create a reversed view.

Comment: Having reviewed a few other options (`descendingIterator()`, `Collections.reverse(List)` and `ListIterator.previous()` I guess that Guava's method is probably both the easiest to use and the most efficient at the same time.

Comment: Creating a `LinkedList` representation of it will require an iteration of the entire `Set`. I want a collection that keeps this up to date itself.

Comment: Then `LinkedHashSet` is not the right tool for the job. How large can the set be?

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 21, the [`addFirst(E e)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#addFirst(E)) method can be used to add an element to the front of a `LinkedHashSet`, relocating it if it already exists in the set.  Using this results in exactly the requested behavior.

```java
SequencedSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
set.addFirst(1);
set.addFirst(2);
set.addFirst(3);
set.addFirst(1);

// 1 then 3 then 2
for (Integer i : set) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

---

Note: Java 21 also has the [`reversed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html#reversed()) method on `LinkedHashSet`.  However, the [`add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) method [doesn't change the order of existing elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), so it won't quite work to solve the problem as described.

> Note that encounter order is *not* affected if an element is *re-inserted* into the set with the add method.

```java
SequencedSet<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>().reversed();
set.add(1);
set.add(2);
set.add(3);
set.add(1);

// 3 then 2 then 1
for (Integer i : set) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```